# trouble with autofac EF DbContext lifetime scope

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I am building an Azure mobile service (WebApi application) and the internet has told me that I need to use a form of DI to manage things like my DbContext.  However, I'm having some issues in that if I mark my DbContext as

.InstancePerRequest()
  **Error**
No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.

InstancePerLifetimeScope()
**Error**
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

I've tried every combination of .InstancePer-blah-blah I thought made sense and, so far, nothing seems to work properly.

Now, one thing that I've noticed is that in the template Azure Mobile Service, a context is created in the controllers initialize method and passed off to the domain manager, like so:

```
 protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request, Services);
    }
```

If I can't figure out how to get autofac working properly, is it too great a sin to instantiate a concrete class in the initialize method if this application will be used as a backend for my mobile app?

Here is my autofac code:

```
var builder = new ConfigBuilder(options, (httpConfig, autofac) =>
        {
            autofac.RegisterType<JapaneseHubDataModel>()
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope(); // <-- the poorly named DbContext

            // register the different repositories
            autofac.RegisterGeneric(typeof(JapaneseHubRepository<>)) // an extension of the prior dbContext
                .As(typeof(IJapaneseHubRepository<>))
                .UsingConstructor(typeof(JapaneseHubDataModel))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            autofac.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UserReferenceRepository<>)) // an extension of JapaneseHubRepository
                .As(typeof(IUserReferenceRepository<>))
                .UsingConstructor(typeof(JapaneseHubDataModel))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            autofac.RegisterType(typeof(UserRepository))
                .As(typeof (IUserRepository))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            // TODO: figure a way to do this the DRY way
            // set the targetted constructors
            autofac.RegisterType<AppSettingController>()
                .UsingConstructor(typeof(IUserReferenceRepository<AppSetting>), typeof(ApiServices));
            autofac.RegisterType<ProgressController>()
                .UsingConstructor(typeof(IUserReferenceRepository<Progress>), typeof(ApiServices));
            autofac.RegisterType<UsageEntryController>()
                .UsingConstructor(typeof(IUserReferenceRepository<UsageEntry>), typeof(ApiServices));
            autofac.RegisterType<ReviewItemController>()
                .UsingConstructor(typeof(IUserReferenceRepository<ReviewItem>), typeof(ApiServices));
            autofac.RegisterType<PurchaseItemController>()
                .UsingConstructor(typeof(IUserReferenceRepository<PurchaseItem>), typeof(ApiServices));
            autofac.RegisterType<UserController>()
                .UsingConstructor(typeof (IUserRepository), typeof (ApiServices));

            // register the controllers with their constructors.
            autofac.Register(c => new AppSettingController(c.Resolve<IUserReferenceRepository<AppSetting>>(),
                c.Resolve<ApiServices>()));
            autofac.Register(c => new ProgressController(c.Resolve<IUserReferenceRepository<Progress>>(),
                c.Resolve<ApiServices>()));
            autofac.Register(c => new UsageEntryController(c.Resolve<IUserReferenceRepository<UsageEntry>>(),
                c.Resolve<ApiServices>()));
            autofac.Register(c => new ReviewItemController(c.Resolve<IUserReferenceRepository<ReviewItem>>(),
                c.Resolve<ApiServices>()));
            autofac.Register(c => new PurchaseItemController(c.Resolve<IUserReferenceRepository<PurchaseItem>>(),
                c.Resolve<ApiServices>()));
            autofac.Register(c => new UserController(c.Resolve<IUserRepository>(),
                c.Resolve<ApiServices>()));
        });
```

the controller:

```
public class AppSettingController : UserReferenceController<AppSetting>
{
    public AppSettingController(IUserReferenceRepository<AppSetting> userRepo, ApiServices services)
        : base(userRepo, services)
    { }
}
```